# IE breaks with error that says that one property is not an object

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, internet-explorer-8

When I started testing my page on IE I found strange errors. IE keep returning error like "XXXXX is null or not an object" where "xxxx" is some property.
For example:

```
var test = 'test string'
if(test.length) ... bla bla
```

and IE breaks with error
**"length is null or not an object"**
I don't understand.... why this stupid browser keeps telling me that the **length** (which is property) is not an object ?!?? I know that length is not a object, because its property !!!!
I'm talking about IE8
I will apreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: I doubt it says that message with the given code in the post. IE8 *would* say "object is null or undefined" when doing `(null).length`, which is not what this post says. Please post a *full minimal test case*.

Comment: (I don't think IE8 supported getters/setters, but it might be prudent to guard against/check changes to String.prototype.)

Comment: pst, pls don't doubt it's displaying the message I'm telling ( screenshot---> http://goo.gl/dfOUk ) ... I can't give you minimal test case because the code is more than 200 000 lines and the lines with errors looks well (just like the example code I gave in the question). ---- and everything works well on chrome and ff... if I fix the error, 5 new similar errors appears :(

Comment: Minimal test case or no issue. Refine the context and verify the values: how are they special? (Also, see if `(""+date).length` makes that particular message go away.)